# What happens when we have WordPress install on main page and after that we install it in a directory

Tags: wordpress, web

I have a website and for now, let's consider it as example.com.Now I have WordPress install on the main page so the link for WordPress is "example.com/wp-admin/". After this, I have to also add WordPress on a directory named "a" so the WordPress admin would be:- "example.co/a/wp-admin/".

So my question is that will anything would be affected in this process in that site?

Comment: Are you moving the site from root to sub-folder or installing another WordPress in sub-folder?

Comment: I am installing ANOTHER WordPress in sub-folder

Comment: So the answer would be that nothing will be affected. Of course, you need to create another db and user.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, And I have tried it on a test website and it was successful.

Comment: But It was giving problem when I installed it with the Softacules app installer. i.e when I installed it automatically, but when I did it manually, it was successful,